# CakePHP Reconnect to DB

Tags: mysql, cakephp, timeout

I have a script that inserts an object into the database and then I have like 20 000 other little objects to be inserted. So I save the other objects into an array and save them afterwards.

But the server sais "MySQL Server has gone away"

Can I reconnect in some way to the database? Or can I disconnect after inserting the big object and after collecting all the small object to reconnect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can in your model.

```
$this->ModelName->getDatasource()->disconnect(); 
    //do stuff
$this->ModelName->getDatasource()->connect();
```

Comment: There is actually a `reconnect()` method that does that: $this->ModelName->getDatasource()->reconnect();