# Prevent CakePHP from automatically connecting to database when instantiating model

Tags: cakephp

The DBA at my company has a script that automatically kills long-running database connections and queries on our production databases. I've written a CakePHP Shell application that runs in a loop, sort of like a daemon, that periodically needs to make database reads and writes. If it runs for too long, the database connection is closed by the maintenance script and my app errors out.

Looking at the CakePHP source, it seems like when a model is instantiated, it automatically tries to connect to the appropriate database. Is there a way to connect to the database only when making a query, then disconnect?

Comment: I don't think there is a clean way of doing this without touching the core, I'll think about it and maybe provide an answer in the morning. But IMHO that DBA policy doesn't make sense, do you know why they do it?

Comment: Although there might be a clean way to achieve what you want to do in CakePHP, I must agree with @luchomolina, there's something not right. It's either the policy, or it's the fact that your shell runs constantly. Isn't it possible to run your shell script periodically (as a cron job?).
I know this comment doesn't solve your problem (which is why I've tried to give a useful answer below), but it's something to think about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can manually connect/disconnect when you need to?

DboSource has lots of methods for you to play with. Here's a list of functions that may be useful:

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('local');

$isconnected = $db->isConnected();  //is the connection open?
$db->close();  //close the connection
$db->reconnect();  //reconnect to the db
```

More methods are listed in the [DboSource API docs](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/dbo-source)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. See a similar question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118519/cakephp-reconnect-to-db

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the callbacks in the AppModel for this.

I'd guess that you could use `beforeFind` and `beforeSafe` to make a connection to the database and then use `afterFind` and `afterSafe` to kill your connection.

As for a 'right' way of opening and closing database connections using core Cake functionality, I'm not sure but Costa's answer seems like a good (and clean!) plan.

(1) http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/922/Database-Configuration (Link stopped working, guess you should look here now: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html )

Comment: I didn't think about using callbacks. I ended up using Costa's suggestion and it works well enough, but callbacks might be cleaner than manually calling connect/disconnect every time I call a function that might block for a long time.