# Is there a way to close mysql connection in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I know how to close mysql connection in php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password","dbname");

// ....some PHP code...

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

But how to close mysql connection in cakephp

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118519/cakephp-reconnect-to-db

Comment: Just a note, that it is better to let server handle the connection unless needed explicitly. When there are too many connections, you might get db error as per my previous experience.

Answer (score 7):

Try this..

```
$this->ModelName->getDatasource()->disconnect();
```

Comment: where i have to write this line?

Comment: In the model where you want to disconnect with database... also see accepted answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098844/prevent-cakephp-from-automatically-connecting-to-database-when-instantiating-mod